# Android: ConstraintLayout: createHorizontalChain() not working

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I'm trying to create a view which contains a variable number of views evenly spread horizontally.
I think the best option is a `ConstraintLayout`, however I tried implementing this on a clean project:

fragment.xml:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".FirstFragment">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/cl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

myFragment.kt:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        container = view.findViewById(R.id.cl)
        buildViews()
    }

    private val views = mutableListOf<AppCompatImageView>()
    private lateinit var container: ConstraintLayout

    private fun buildViews() {

        val viewLp =
            ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)

        repeat(6) {
            val view = AppCompatImageView(context)
            //I used a random vector drawable here
            view.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(requireContext(), R.drawable.ic_baseline_account_circle_10))
            view.layoutParams = viewLp
            view.id = RelativeLayout.generateViewId()
            container.addView(view)
            views.add(view)
        }

        val set = ConstraintSet()
        set.clone(container)

        val ids = views.mapTo(mutableListOf(), { it.id }).toIntArray()

        set.createHorizontalChain(
            ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,
            ConstraintSet.LEFT,
            ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,
            ConstraintSet.RIGHT,
            ids,
            null,
            ConstraintSet.CHAIN_SPREAD
        )
        set.applyTo(container)
    }
```

but this gives me the following result:
[image: screen]

I expect an horizontal chain like this:
[image]

Note that the `ImageView`s are all correctly drawn, they're just all in the same spot.
From the debug, I can see that the constraints in the `set` are all correct (first view is connected to parent and second view, second view to first and third and so on...). Also, the ConstraintLayout is correctly stretching to the whole screen width, so the views should fit.
I also tried to manually assign constraints to each view and I got the same result.

What am I missing here?

Comment: you can try to change android:layout_height="wrap_content" to android:layout_height="0" in your ConstraintLayout with android:id="@+id/cl"

Comment: This question looks simple, but, unfortunatly, I don't understand kotlin

Comment: @AlexRmcf I don't see why changing the height would make an impact on this, however I tried and got the same result.
as for kotlin, there's nothing strange going on here, `repeat()` is basically a `for` (executes the code 6 times), `val set` is just a variable but get's mistakenly highlighted by SO, `ids` is an array which contains the ids of the views, and stuff like `AppCompatImageView(context)` is equivalent to `new AppCompatImageView(context)`. the rest is pretty much java code

Comment: Ok. Maybe I did not understand something. For now i see what you have got. Can you explain me what do you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be other problems, but one issue that your code has is that it shares one set of layout params among the views. Each view needs its own set of layout params to store its layout constraints. Move

```
 val viewLp =
        ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
```

inside the `repeat(6)` loop and you will get a better result.